# Writing to stream C# not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, stream, portable-class-library

I want to write to a file using StreamWriter, but my problem is that my stream cannot write. I have successfully read that file using StreamReader, but I cannot figure out how to write it. Here is how I created the stream:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(Login)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BSoft.Resources.LoggedHistory.json");
```

And

```
stream.CanWrite
```

Returns false.

I am using .NETPortable v4.5, and I cannot install System.IO.FileSystem also

Comment: Embedded resources cannot be modified, that's why `CanWrite` is false. Use `IsolatedStorage` for these purposes.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Gusman, how should I use IsolatedStorage?

Comment: It looks like I cannot add io.IsolatedStorage either

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=isolatedstorage+.net+portable

Comment: embedded assembly can not be edited but you can create physical resource and write into it

Comment: Finnaly found an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin#debugging-embedded-resources) very useful.

So the main problem is that in.NetPortable you cannot use System.IO.FileSystem, because there are many differences between iOS, android, and windows file systems. So you should use a [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#Registration), by creating an interface:

```
...
namespace BSoft
{
 public interface ISaveAndLoad
 {
    void SaveFile(string filename, string text);
    bool CheckExistingFile(string filename);
    string ReadFile(string filename);
 }
}
```

And adding dependencies for each platform, here is an example for iOS:

IOS:

```
... 

using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using BSoft.iOS;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SaveReadFiles_iOS))] /// !! Important
namespace BSoft.iOS
{
 public class SaveReadFiles_iOS : ISaveAndLoad
 {
    public SaveReadFiles_iOS(){}

    public void SaveFile(string filename, string text)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
    }

    public bool CheckExistingFile(string filename)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        return File.Exists(filePath);
    }

    public string ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        if(File.Exists(filePath))
            return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        return "";
    }
   }
  }
```

Also, there are more factors to consider like adding xamarin. forms package and calling Forms.Init() in each platform AppDelegate class.

Finally, you can use this dependency by calling them like this:

```
DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>().CheckExistingFile("LoggedHistory.json")
```